# Лексическая сочетаемость слова "голос"

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли говорить "произнести мрачным голосом", "сказать тихим голосом"

Comment: Думаю что можно, а что Вас настораживает? Вбейте в гугл, посмотрите примеры. Некоторые из них вполне себе заслуживают доверия, как мне кажется. В конце концов "Наш Константин берёт гитару / И тихим голосом поёт", не умел бы петь - сказал бы.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, сомнения вызывает вопрос: не является ли избыточным или даже тавтологичным сочетание глагола, характеризующего речь, и существительного "голос"? Действительно, тот или иной "голос" присутствует при *любой* форме речевого самовыражения, поэтому в чистом виде "**сказал он голосом**" или "**запел он голосом**" звучит крайне тавтологично. Причина в том, что факт использования голоса при таких глаголах оказывается бесполезной информацией (ясно, что не молча сказал и вряд ли по-рыбьи запел). Однако новая информация возникает при конкретизации: как именно сказал (*каким* голосом или с каким видом). В одних случаях можно охарактеризовать манеру речи (**сказал мрачно** или **с мрачным видом**), в других - *голос* (**сказал мрачным голосом**), причём иногда голос удаётся конкретизировать отдельным существительным (шёпот, фальцет...), а чаще требуется прилагательное. Из общих соображений можно принять и "**сказал тихим голосом**", хотя это и более многословно, чем "**сказал тихо**"; возможно, какому-то автору первый вариант может понадобиться для "единства стиля" и т. п. Соответственно, оба выражения из вопроса вполне возможны.

Comment: А какая смысловая разница будет в этом предложении: Я не приказывал готовить шлюпок, — тихим голосом/тихо сказал капитан (Б. Житков);

Comment: Смысловой разницы нет, только стиль другой. О важном человеке можно и многословнее сказать  ("тихо сказал" больше подходит для робкой речи). В каком-то смысле здесь тихий "командный голос".

Comment: А может быть,  сказал тихо, потому что нельзя было говорить громко. Одно дело -  это возможность говорить в полный голос,  а другое -  характеристика состояния человека. Иногда, раздражаясь, люди не кричат, а напротив, говорят подчеркнуто  тихо. Разве это не смысловая разница?

Comment: Эти различия - _за пределами_ двух данных выражений, в контексте. Сочетаемость их с внешними элементами может быть разной, внутренних же смысловых различий я не вижу: и то, и другое о _голосе_, не о сопутствующей тишине ("тихо" едва ли подразумевает "без зубовного скрежета" и пр.). Вот "мрачно" может подразумевать мрачный вид, не только голос.

Answer (score 0):

БТС: [**сказа́ть**](https://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), скажу, скажешь; сказанный; -зан, -а, -о; ***св.***
**1. (*нсв.* говорить)**. *(что).* Выразить словесно мысли, мнения, сообщать (устно или письменно); **произнести.**

В словаре Ушакова:
**произнести**
1. Выговорить, воспроизвести в членораздельной речи.
*Правильно произнести иностранное слово. Произнести гласный звук "а".*
2. **Сказать**, высказать.
*В гостях не произнес ни слова.* ***Крякнул и произнес хриплым голосом*** (Пушкин).

Я думаю, что вполне грамотно так говорить.
Сказать (как?) тихим голосом (= тихо); произнести (как?) мрачным голосом (= мрачно).

*Я не приказывал готовить шлюпок, — **тихим голосом сказал** капитан* (Б. Житков); *Филипп, — **сказал** он **голосом настолько нежным и ласковым**, что юноша вздрогнул и заплакал от счастья...* (О. де Бальзак); *Да, я подлец! Несомненный подлец, – **произнес** он вдруг **мрачным голосом*** (Ф. М. Достоевский); *В конце концов Карлсон **сказал грустным голосом**...* (А. Линдгрен)

Answer (score 0):

Я согласна с Alex_ander **в части тавтологии**. Действительно, сочетание ***говорить голосом*** кажется избыточным, а при наличии определения приходится делать выбор среди  парных вариантов: ***сказал тихо/мрачно*** и ***сказал тихим/мрачным голосом.***

Рассмотрим вариант ***тихо/тихим голосом***, семантика его может быть разная. Во-первых, тихо говорят в том случае, когда нежелательно говорить громко. Во-вторых, тихий голос может иметь различные оттенки, например:  Скажи мне что-то тихим голосом (нежным, проникновенным).

А вот вариант ***мрачно/мрачным голосом*** таких смысловых оттенков не имеет, поэтому выбор делается по структуре предложения, то есть используется тот вариант, который удобнее вписывается в предложение.

Примеры:

Он был боливиец ― высокий, седоватый, **с мягкими манерами.** Он сказал **тихим голосом:** ― Садитесь, доктор Голяховский. [Владимир Голяховский. Русский доктор в Америке (1984-2001)]

― Ты, Костя, в жизни чего-нибудь хотел по-настоящему? ― Не знаю, ― **тихо сказал** Костя. ― Ну вот! А говоришь― скорей! [Валерий Медведев. Баранкин, будь человеком! (1957)]

Не переживай, ― **мрачно сказал** Авель. [Виктор Пелевин. Желтая стрела (1993)]

Аркан у вас есть? ― Есть, ― **мрачным голосом ответил** Еремей.  [И. Л. Солоневич. Две силы (1953)]